# mysql ERROR 1064 cannot find syntax error

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1064

I was trying to add a table to my database. The script being after the error message. I cannot see the syntax error. I change various things but to no avail. I am sure some with fresh eyes will see it right away. Please help.

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 3: You have
>   an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL
>   server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ' send_payment_instructions
>   tinyint default '1', photo_id_list
>   varchar(250), feat' at line 29

```
use lfs;
drop table if exists tm_export;
create table tm_export(
product_id_for_member int default null,
member_id varchar(30) default 'hiburygalleria',
sku int(10) not null,
stock_amount int(10) default '1',
unlimited_stock tinyint default '0',
category_id int(5),
title varchar(50),
subtitle varchar(50),
body varchar(2048) not null,
is_new tinyint default '0',
start_price decimal not null,
reserve_price decimal,
buy_now_price decimal,
fpo_amount decimal,
fpo_duration int,
fpo_to char,
av_bidders_only tinyint default '0',
auction_length tinyint default '7',
auction_end_time time,
delivery_pickup_allowed tinyint default '1',
delivery_must_pickup tinyint,
delivery_is_free tinyint default '0',
delivery_price varchar(200),
payment_bank_deposit tinyint default '1',
payment_credit_card tinyint default '0',
payment_cash tinyint default '1',
payment_safe_trader tinyint default '0',
payment_other varchar,
send_payment_instructions tinyint default '1',
photo_id_list varchar(250),
feature tinyint default '0',
display_bold tinyint default '0',
gallery tinyint default '0',
primary key (sku)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

With MySQL, you **have** to give a parameter to varchar. So change `payment_other varchar` to `payment_other varchar(1024)`, for instance. Or `payment_other text` if you don't have a limit in mind (although I think MySQL's text type has a limitation).

Concerning integers, it works with and without quotes. I prefer without for obvious reasons, though.

Comment: Thanks Vincent. It worked! Thanks Evan as well for editing. I forgot to format the code correctly.

Comment: Nice catch @vicent